# Please reconcile these chat accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

Today I learned that I have two chat accounts.  [This one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/25779/monica-cellio) seems to be the main one, but there's also [this one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/17863/monica-cellio), which IIRC was the result of visiting one chat thread once from English.SE.  I don't know what the implications are of having two chat identities, but I gather that I'm only supposed to have one.  Can these be merged somehow?  Or can the stray one from English.SE be deleted without harming anything else?

Comment: Will do when I'm at a proper PC... on vacation at the moment

Comment: @MarcGravell - thanks, and no rush.  Enjoy your vacation!

Comment: @MarcGravell, just checking if you're back from vacation?

Comment: All done; sorry

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks!